# GitHub->JRA connector/integration

Tags: github

I'm looking for a tool to integrate GitHub with JIRA, specifically when there is an event originating in a defined GitHub repository that we own, a custom action would be performed in JIRA. There is no need for the connection to work the opposite way (that is JIRA to GitHub).

It doesn't matter if the application is free or paid (as long as the pricing is not based on the number of JIRA users), if it requires a public server (e.g. in case it uses GitHub's webhooks as a trigger for actions) or whether it has a fancy GUI or just a CLI interface used for configuration.

### Required support for GitHub events

- Pull request created
- Release created

### Required support for JIRA actions

- Add a comment to a JIRA issue whose ID is mentioned in the GitHub event
- Transition issue from one status to other

### What I already know about

- "[Git Integration for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xiplink.jira.git.jira_git_plugin/cloud/overview)" plugin - while we need only the simplest fraction of its functionality, the price based on the number of our users in JIRA (500+) is out of our budget for such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Syncfusion Data Integration Platform](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/data-integration).

You need to host Syncfusion Data Integration server on some server (cloud/on premise).

**GitHub Events**

1. Create a HTTP server using ListenHTTP processor which acts as a payload URL.
2. Create Webhooks in your GitHub repository for required events.

**JIRA actions**

3. Create a workflow to parse the payload response when event triggers.
4. Parse JSON value and get relevant information and store as attributes using EvaluateJsonPath and UpdateAttribute processor.Parse Jira issue ID from GitHub pull request comments and generate Atlassian REST API.
5. Store your credentials in database or local file and read it using ExecuteSQL or GetFile processor.
6. Add comment in Jira using its REST API with InvokeHTTP processor. Also you can Transition issue with Jira REST API using our processor.

Whenever pull request is created in GitHub, payload URL will get JSON data from GitHub Webhook and it will be parsed and added as a comment in Jira using the  workflow defined in Syncfusion Data Integration Platform.

You can download the sample data flow [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/7z/GitHubToJira1464822637)

[image: Github Jira integration using Syncfusion Data Integration platform]

The Data Integration Platform available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue) and flat licensing is available even otherwise (not counting the number of users).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Wow. I checked all the processors it has and it looks super flexible. JFYI, I'll keep this open for a while but eventually will pick an accepted answer.